# What is the term for the act of breaking up one long drawn out note into multiple beats?

Tags: terminology

I’m slowly learning music terminology and I’m trying to have a discussion with a musician friend about something but I’m not sure what you call this.

My initial thought was an arpeggio but that’s related to playing the individual notes of a chord separately. I’m referring to breaking up a single long sound into several.

Take Tiesto’s rendition of “adagio for strings” as an example. The trance version of this orchestral song has a sort of “stutter” to it but it has the same general melody.

Edit: here are the two versions.

Original orchestral arrangement:

Tiesto’s Trance rendition:

Note that in the Tiesto version there is both unbroken and “chopped up” versions. The original melody starts at 0:36 and the trance-y version starts at about 1:13

Comment: I have heard this in mandolin arrangements of songs as well, long notes becoming something more like tremolo.

Answer (score 1):

There no specific music theory term for what Tiesto is doing in this arrangement. It's possible (likely?) he's applying one or more electronic effects, perhaps some kind of echo, delay, or loop. There's a technique called "chopping" that could have been used, though chopping is associated with breaking up a vocal track to create a new, different vocal track.

Were I talking about Tiesto's version to a musician friend, I would say something like "rather than keep the long, sustained notes, he repeats each note on each beat of its duration with some kind of echo or decay effect added to each repetition."

Comment: Maybe "chopping up the notes" would work? That might avoid confusion with "chopping" in the sense you wrote above, as it conveys that every note is cut up.